# MVC3 Html.DropDownListFor with both static and dynamic values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'd like to populate a Html.DropDownListFor with both static and dynamic values in my controller.  I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.  I've tried a few different approaches, but most center around (1) define the static values in a variable, (2) try to append the dynamic values (3) pass all values via the viewModel to my partial view.

Here is a sample of the above approach.

```
//retrieve categories from DB
List<Category> categoryFromDb = new GetCategory().GetCategoryDropdownList(MySession.Current.AccountId).FindAll(c => c.StageId == currentStage);

//local variable with static values and trying to add the dynamic values from above
    var categoryDropDown = new [] {
                                      new {CategoryId = "", CategoryName = "Select Activity"},
                                      new {CategoryId = "0", CategoryName = "Note"},
                                      new {CategoryId = categoryFromDb[0], CategoryName = categoryFromDb[3]}  //THIS IS THE LINE I CAN'T FIGURE OUT
                                  };

    var viewModel = new ActivityTimelineViewModel
    {
        ActivityTimeline = new GetActivity().GetActivityTimeline(MySession.Current.AccountId, MySession.Current.CandidateId),
        CategoryList = categoryDropDown,
        Date = DateTime.Today
    };
```

I'm sure given my novice ability I am missing something simple.
-Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to find a common type and than you can put them into a combined collection.  Can you make the static values of type Category?

```
List<Category> categoryFromDb = new GetCategory().GetCategoryDropdownList(MySession.Current.AccountId).FindAll(c => c.StageId == currentStage);
var staticCategories = new[]
{
    new Category{CategoryId = "", CategoryName = "Select Activity"},
    new Category{CategoryId = "0", CategoryName = "Note"}
};

var combinedCategories = staticCategories.Union(categoryFromDb);
```

Or if the Category won't work than put them into a SelectListItem like this.

```
List<SelectListItem> selectItemsFromDB =
new GetCategory().GetCategoryDropdownList(MySession.Current.AccountId).FindAll(
    c => c.StageId == currentStage)
    .Select(c=> new SelectListItem{Value = c.CategoryId, Text = c.CategoryName});
var staticCategories = new[]
{
    new SelectListItem{Value = "", Text = "Select Activity"}
    new SelectListItem{Value = "0", Text = "Note"}
};

var combinedCategories = staticCategories.Union(selectItemsFromDB);
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I actually started going down your first approach after I posted my questions, but I ran into an issue wit the constructors.  I ended up using your second approach with one small edit as my CategoryId is an int.`.Select(c=> new SelectListItem{Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(), Text = c.CategoryName}).ToList();`

Comment: Figured out my constructor issue.  Forgot to add the default/nullary constructor when I explicitly created my own constructor.  That was causing an ORM db call to fail.